# Pipe STDOUT to an image?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, git, linux-terminal

Recently, I wanted to run a terminal command like `git show <hash>` and save the output to an image, a PNG preferably.

I googled it quite a bit and found some neat tricks, with the import command notably, but nothing that would reliably capture STDOUT and save it as an image.

So, I thought I'd ask the brain trust here. Anyone have a tested and verified solution for Linux?

Comment: Just to be clear, you want it to render the text as an image (so when you look at the you can read the text), right? Because the answers for that could be more complicated than "I want the ASCII/Unicode bytes of the text to become bytes of the image file, even though it'll make an image that just looks like random/corrupt/garbage pixels" or "I want the ASCII/Unicode bytes of the text to be stored in the metadata or some hidden field of the image file format".

Comment: Render that output as readable text, yes. Preserving color if possible because I have "force_color_prompt=yes" set in my .bashrc file, but I can try temporarily flipping that setting if it'll make a difference.

Answer (score 3):

How to convert text to an image has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826379/image-magick-converting-text-to-image-is-there-a-way-to-center-the-text-to-t
That answer provides various variants on how to do this with the ImageMagick tools.

Please note: This will only work reliably if the output of your command is plain text.
If there is any sort of fancy formatting (like ncurses stuff) the results can be quite unpredictable.

Comment: Convert, yeah. I tried a few things with that, couldn't get any of them to work at all. Probably because I have "force_color_prompt=yes" set in my .bashrc file and that fancy formatting thing you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer, listing some possibilities:

There is a number of progams you can use to render text to images, for example:

- `convert` from ImageMagick/GraphicsMagick
- `pbmtext` from NetPBM, renders to Portable Bitmap
- `paps`, renders to Postscript using Pango
- `enscript`, renders to Postscript

But converting a different format to PNG shouldn't be a problem.

Of these, only `enscript` supports colors via "special escapes". These are not the same as the terminal escapes, so you'll to convert them with awk/perl etc.

Another option is to render the whole thing in an xterm, and screenshot.

As you can see, all of these are quite complicated, at will require non-trivial effort to make them work. Which is no surprise, because basically you want to replicate the whole rendering part of your terminal.

It might be easier to just store the output itself, and retrieve it in a terminal when you want to look at it.

Comment: So it's definitely non-trivial, as I've come to realize. Bitmaps would work but aren't that appealing as they are not compressed. Saving as postscript might yield some desirable options, the goal is to preserve git show <hash> output in a form that can be shared with others (think portfolio). Or maybe there's an even better option I haven't thought of yet.

Comment: As I said, the final format is not the problem - you can freely convert from PBM to PNG, or from Postscript to PNG in a final step. The main problem is rendering text with color escapes. *Preserving* `git show` output can be done by just storing it in a file with `git show > xxx` or `git show --pretty=blah > xxx`. If you need it for some kind of resume, converting that to whatever commands your text processing system needs will be vastly easier than converting it to a picture.